# Is READ UNCOMMITTED equivalent to non-ACID (BASE) transaction management?

Tags: nosql, isolation-level, acid

Relational databases are often associated to the ACID properties, which "protect" data but may hinder performance, even on a single node.

Isolation levels (the I in ACID) shield transactions from various types of interference from other concurrent transaction. The greater the isolation level (think, SERIALIZABLE) the greater the performance penalty, because you are intentionally limiting the number of concurrent transactions on the same data set.

BASE databases essentially follow an optimistic approach to conflicts. Conflicts can appear, but they will eventually be solved and all replicas will agree on the same value (eventual consistency).

Is the READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level equivalent, in terms of performance, to using a NoSQL/BASE database? It seems that, in both cases, you avoid locks and gain in terms of performance while losing some consistency.

Comment: I in ACID isn't isolation level, it is isolation, period. Ie level serializable. Otherwise it's not ACID. But the mnemonic "ACID" is a poor way to present the associated transaction model.

Answer (score 0):

The C in ACID and the Consistency in "Eventual Consistency" do not refer to the same consistency term. While the first one means that the constraints imposed on the database (foreign keys, unique, and so on) are enforced, the second one refers to database clusters, where strong consistency means, that after a write confirmation, all clients read the new data, no longer the the old (in the case of an update). With eventual consistency, this guarantee is not given.
Hence, also Isolation from ACID is not very much related to strong or eventual consistency.

Talking about isolation levels is only useful in environments, where you have multi-command transactions (as, for example, most SQL databases).
A transaction in SQL can always be rollbacked,
so all changes, that are performed during this transaction are tentative until the final commit. The isolation level "read uncommitted" had to change the
current working data set and revert these changes on rollback. This leaves
open questions, for example, how to deal with the situation, that some numeric value is incremented in (uncommitted) Transaction 1, and then doubled in Transaction 2. Transaction 2 commits, Transaction 1 rollbacks. What is the correct value? You see, locking is necessary here, too, to avoid ambiguous situations.

Situation is different when Transaction 2 only reads from the database, while Transaction 1 changes it. Isolation-Level Read Uncommitted provides Transaction 2 with the new value, while with Read Committed, the previous value would be visible.

However, in both situations, both values (old and new) have to be retained, because Transaction 1 could also rollback. Locking is not necessary with both variants when Multiversion Concurrency Control (MVCC) is used.

As a result of these considerations, most SQL databases do not exhibit "dirty reads" at all, but overachieve the level "Read Uncommitted" and treat it exactly as the "Read Committed" isolation level. This is fully conforming to the SQL standard.